# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+1/x)^{x^2}}{e^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Could anybody show me step by step why the following equality holds?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+1/x)^{x^2}}{e^x} = e^{-1/2}$$

The most obvious method gives you 1 as an answer, but I understand that only the *limit* of $(1+1/x)^x$ is $e$, but expression is not actually equal to $e$. And now I am stuck.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please make sure I interpreted the exponentiation correctly when applying MathJax--there is a pretty big difference between $(1+1/x)^{x^2}$ and $((1+1/x)^x)^2$.

Comment: The title was hilarious...

Comment: Could tell us more about your background? There's a handful of methods to be used to answer this, you'll want something you can grasp I guess..

Comment: Maybe try L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Thx for editing my post ;) (first time here...). I am a beginer in applied physics course in russian university (first year out of four to bachelors degree). I met this limit as an extra question on my exam.

Comment: And, L'Hôpital's rule was a bizarre.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compute the limit of the logarithm of your function:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\frac{(1+1/x)^{x^2}}{e^x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2\log(1+1/x)-x)
$$
Now set $x=1/t$:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2\log(1+1/x)-x)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t)-t}{t^2}
$$

> The limit becomes $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-t^2/2+o(t^2)-t}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$. So your original limit is $e^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thx very much for your help) i tried logarithm but didnt come to the part of setting x =1/t. It was very helpful, the question is answered:)

Comment: @dimaastronom Such a substitution allows using Taylor expansion more easily, so it's something that should be tried when you have a limit at $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Say $$y = \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}}{e^x}$$ Then $\log(y) =x^2 \log\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)-x$. We change variables $t=\frac{1}{x}$. Then $\log(y)=\frac{1}{t^2} \log(1+t) - \frac{1}{t}$.

Near $t=0$, $$\log(1+t) = t - \frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}- \frac{t^4}{4} +\ldots$$

So near $t=0$, $$\log(y) = \left(\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{2} + O(t)\right) - \frac{1}{t} = - \frac{1}{2} + O(t) $$

Going back in terms of $x$, for large $x$

$$\log(y) = - \frac{1}{2} + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$

Hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \log(y) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

exponentiating we have the result.