Find the $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+1/x)^{x^2}}{e^x}$
Find the $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}}{e^x}.$$
I know that the result is equal to $e^{-1/2}$, but I am curious why I can't substitute one of the $x$ outside result in $\left[\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x \right]^x$, and the inner part will result in $e$ and, therefore, the whole thing will become $e^x$, which after division will become $1$ instead of $e^{-1/2}$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084648/42969, or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1483711/42969, or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3302597/42969 – all found with Approach0

I have seen the process of going through it, but i wonder is there other approach to solve it except using l'hopital rule and also the method of expansion?

For the same reason why you can't substitute $0$ for $1/x$ to conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+1/x)^x= \lim_{x\to\infty}1^x = 1$. Such substitutions just don't work.

Thanks for the explanation.

To expand on @Ennar's point, take logarithms. Define $f(x):=x\ln(1+1/x)-1$. As $x\to\infty$, $f\to0$, which tells you nothing about the behaviour of $xf$.


is there other approach to solve it except using l'hopital rule and also the method of expansion?

You can write a solution using the Squeeze theorem that essentially bounds the function by its Taylor sums, but without the need to prove that these bounds are indeed taken from its expansion.

The idea to prove the bounds comes from this answer by xpaul.
Let's take $t \ge 0$. This implies that $1\le 1+t$, which in turn implies $\color{purple}{\frac{1}{1+t }\le 1}$. We now notice the following

For $t \ge 0$ we have $\color{purple}{\frac{t}{1+t }\le  t}$. Thus
$$
x-\ln(1+x) = \int_{0}^{x} \color{purple}{\frac{t}{1+t }}\, \mathrm{d}t \le \int_{0}^{x} \color{purple}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t   = \frac{x^2}{2}\tag{1}
$$
For $t \ge 0$ we have $\color{purple}{\frac{t^2}{1+t }\le  t^2}$. Thus
$$
-x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\ln(1+x) = \int_{0}^{x} \color{purple}{\frac{t^2}{1+t }}\, \mathrm{d}t \le \int_{0}^{x} \color{purple}{t^2}\, \mathrm{d}t   = \frac{x^3}{3}\tag{2}
$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get that for $x> 0$
\begin{align*}
x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\le \ln(1+x) \le x-\frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} \color{blue}{\implies} - \frac12 \le \frac{1}{x^{2}}\ln\left(1+x\right)-\frac{1}{x}\le \frac{x}{3} - \frac12 
\end{align*}
So by the  Squeeze theorem, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\ln\left(1+x\right)-\frac{1}{x} =- \frac12 \tag{3} 
$$
Lastly, we return to the original problem and see that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}}{\mathrm{exp}(x)} &\overset{\color{green}{x\to 1/x}}{=}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}{\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\\
& =\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln\left(\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}{\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)\right)\\
 &=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\ln\left(1+x\right)-\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
& \overset{(3)}{=} \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac12\right) 
\end{align*}
as desired.
